# Can I FTP data into AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to upload content into S3 using a standard FTP client like FileZilla? I am unsure at the moment how best to get data uploaded in bulk. Thanks

Comment: If you're on Windows the free Cloudberry Lab does simple FTP-equivalent stuff. Just enter your access keys, which you can find at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home -> access keys.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

S3 doesn't support ftp directly, but for the mac, you can use a tool like cyberduck.io  and on windows cloudberry has a pretty complete set of tools (including some free ones):

- http://cyberduck.io/
- http://www.cloudberrylab.com/

To the best of my knowledge, filezilla doesn't support s3, though I wouldn't be surprised if they do someday.

Comment: I like CrossFTP for that, it can upload in parallel, resume, S3/Glacier support, etc...

Comment: You mean that ticket opened 5 years ago? Something tells me it's not going to get implemented.

Comment: Filezilla now offers a Pro Version (10 USD) that easily connects to AWS S3 buckets.

Answer (score 4):

Filezilla Pro now offers S3 connectivity out of the box. It costs 10 USD and works great.

The download is a little bit hard to find. Either you click the promotion banner (if available) or you click "Home" on the FileZilla page, then click on the big grey "Download FileZilla Client" button. In the popup you can choose between the two versions.

[image]

To connect to S3 with FileZilla Pro follow these steps:

Open FileZilla Pro's Sitemanager with cmd / str "S" or click on the Sitemanager icon that is on the top left corner of the main window.

- Create a new site with "New Site".
- Enter "s3.amazonaws.com" as "Host".
- Choose "S3- Amazon Simple Storage Service" as protocol.
- Enter your AWS user name as "User".
- Enter your AWS password as "Password".
- Click "Connect" and your good to go.

[image]

Comment: instead user username and password I had to enter AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY