# FTP files into AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a service out there that will enable me to ftp files in the usual way and deposit them in my S3 bucket? I have an ancient service which spits out a data dump every night and currently ftps it up to an ftp server where it is just stored on disk. I would really like not to have to put another script in to take the file from the ftp server onto S3. I can not get under the good of the data-dump script but do have ability to change the ftp details. So, is there anyway without incurring additional overhead and taking on any extra moving parts to just point the data-dump at a 'virtual ftp server' which will take care of getting the file into S3.

I think S3 is great, but most of the world of big enterprise software still runs on Ftp. Surely there is an interface between out there somewhere in cloud land?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just doing a google I discovered this: http://www.ftp2cloud.com/ftp-amazon-s3/

Please remember FTP does not use encryption and is subject to sniffing attacks.

Comment: Also just a note- you could set up your own "cloud gateway" server using an FTP server like FileZilla Server and something like WebDrive or CloudBerry Drive to map the drive. May not be ideal for mega-heavy loads.

Re: Sniffing: You should use FTP-SSL (aka FTP-TLS) to avoid plaintext password transmission. It's supported by FileZilla Server.

Answer (score 2):

Filezilla now offers a Pro version (10 USD) that easily connects to AWS S3 buckets. From my experience this is the best and fastest FTP solution available.

See also these threads with instructions how to download and setup:

[Can I FTP data into AWS S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079069/can-i-ftp-data-into-aws-s3/45387513#45387513)

[How to setup Filezilla Pro to access to my s3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293159/how-to-setup-filezilla-pro-to-access-to-my-s3-bucket/45387411#45387411)

Answer (score 1):

can use encryption, but automating it is a next step.

Step 1: Get your Public DNS address. You can find it under your instance's info, at the bottom.

Step 2: Find your .pem key that you got when you got your instance.

Step 3: Open FileZilla.

Step 4: Go to the FileZilla settings, and on the left, click SFTP.

Step 5: Add a new private key. (Your .pem key)

Step 6: If you are using a .pem key you must convert it, otherwise it will not work.

Step 7: At the top in the Quickconnect bar, put your Public DNS in the host, ec2-user, port 22 (Port 22 is SFTP rather than FTP, AWS will kick back FTP.), and NO PASSWORD.