# How to setup Filezilla Pro to access to my s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, filezilla

I bought Filezilla Pro that supports Amazon S3, so pls how to setup Filezilla Pro to access into my bucket? Thank you

Comment: I don't have that version, but does something different appear when you go File / Site Manager / Protocol?

Comment: @John Yes, it does. It offers S3 connectivity out of the box (which the plain version doesn´t have).

Comment: Where did you buy pro? I can not find it anywhere on their website...

Answer (score 18):

You can connect to S3 with FileZilla Pro with these simple steps:

Open FileZilla Pro's *Site Manager* with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> (Windows) or click on the Site Manager icon that is on the top left corner of the main window.

- Create a new site with "New Site".
- Enter "s3.amazonaws.com" as "Host".
- Choose "S3- Amazon Simple Storage Service" as protocol.
- Enter your AWS *Access Key ID*.
- Enter your AWS *Secret Access Key*.
- Click "Connect" and your good to go.

[image: FileZilla Pro v3.36.0 (macOS 10.13.6)]
([Previous version screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4mKn.png))

Works like a charm. Highly recommended. Very much worth the 10 bucks.

Comment: How do you even get pro version? I have looked and can not find a way to give them money... doesnt make sense.

Comment: @timothymarois They kind of hid it very successfully... ;0) Check the banner on top of their [homepage](https://filezilla-project.org/)

Comment: I still cannot find anything on their site for purchasing. Found the website to buy but it says it's only for windows.... Their download page gives the option for linux so I am a bit confused. Guess they don't like money :/

Comment: @Jeremy They have removed the banner and have setup a different site to buy FileZilla Pro. Try this link: https://filezillapro.com/ftp/mac/

Answer (score 18):

One crucial addition to the above answer:

What is my S3 username and password?

Username = Access Key (preferrably an IAM user with only the rights to access the specific S3 buckets (s3:List*) as well as get and put objects permissions.

Password = Secret access key, which you get once you create a new access key. Store this one in a secure space, because you cannot recover it.

Comment: This should be appended to the top answer so it doesn't go unnoticed. Thanks!

Comment: note, I needed to check "bypass proxy" in the Advanced tab. I was getting this error: Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known".

Answer (score 14):

When using Filezilla Pro to connect AWS S3 , do not forget to add the Bucket name (and any sub folders under the bucket) in "Default remote directory" section of Advanced tab. 
Please refer the screen shot.
[image]

Comment: This is the only thing that would make it work.  The default bucket must be in there.

Answer (score 4):

1. In your Amazon Web Services dashboard (https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/security_credential) create a Access Key ID and Secret Key pair
2. Launch FileZilla Pro
3. Open Site Manager (File, Site Manager or Ctrl+S)

[image: Open Site Manager]

4. Click New Site and give it a name

[image: New Site]

5. In Protocol select “S3 - Amazon Simple Storage Service” from the drop-down menu. The host name is automatically filled.

[image: Protocol]

6. In Logon Type select “Normal”

[image: Logon Type]

7. In the Access Key ID box enter the Access Key ID you created
8. In the Secret Access Key box enter the Secret Key you created
9. Click “Connect”

[image: Connect]

You can watch also our video tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea6WVWADQJc and if you like it please consider to [subscribe](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMlhJXAux-IK-l9R2EweeEQ?sub_confirmation=1)!