# How to copy folders and files available at FTP server to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp

I would like to copy all my folders and files available from FTP server to Amazon S3 bucket.

Tried to find the information on web to find the tools or AWS S3 provides any APIS for copy folders and files from FTP server.

Any tools or pointers to links would be helpful

Comment: I think you should be able to achive this by using curl and s3cmd. E.g. pipe the output of curl into s3cmd

Comment: Since my all data is in FTP server, how can i achieve with curl?

Answer (score 3):

I use Filezilla Pro that easily connects to AWS S3 buckets. From my experience this is the best and fastest "FTP" solution available.

See also these threads with instructions how to download and setup:

[Can I FTP data into AWS S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079069/can-i-ftp-data-into-aws-s3/45387513#45387513)

[How to setup Filezilla Pro to access to my s3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293159/how-to-setup-filezilla-pro-to-access-to-my-s3-bucket/45387411#45387411)

Comment: is Filezilla pro able to copy a lot of directories and files from FTP to S3 bucket ??

Comment: @GhyathDarwish I use it all the time for exactly this and it really works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

The [AWS Command Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) can be used to copy multiple files and folders to Amazon S3. It also has a `sync` command that can intelligently copy on new or modified files.

This has nothing to do with your origin being an FTP server. Rather, it's a means of copying from some source (Windows, Linux, Mac) to Amazon S3. You can call the command from outside of your FTP software (eg as a script triggered hourly).